# If I'm scanning for input, how do I accept a single character as input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In class, we've learned the `Scanner` class for input, so we say

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)
```

and then if we wanted to scan an integer, one would say

```
num = keyboard.nextInt()
```

for example, or if it was a String,

```
keyboard.nextLine()
```

How does one do it for a character?

```
keyboard.nextChar() doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't seem to work", what *actually* happens?

Comment: @GregHewgill There is no `nextChar()` method in `Scanner` class.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: That's true. I'm trying to encourage the OP to provide more information than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was self-explanatory. By doesn't work I mean it doesn't work with the compiler, and it produces an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `keyboard.next()`? If you really need a `char`, use `keyboard.next().charAt(0)`.

Comment: letterGuess = keyboard.next();

The above returns an error unfortunately. Exactly what is the second option doing?

Comment: When you say "returns an error" you have to say what the error is. Does the error happen when you compile or when you run it? What is the text of the error? What is the code that produces the error? You should update your question to include answers to everything I'm mentioned in this comment.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'll keep that in mind for the future. I simply implemented the suggested `keyboard.next().charAt(0)` option, and it works well now, so I'm content. Thanks for the help.